# Plotting Values as Rectangles Spanning Unequal Ranges of X

Tags: r

I would like to plot two y values for two ranges of x values that are non-congruent. I have tried the `plot(rect())` command unsuccessfully.

My inputs for x ranges and y values respectively are:

```
[1, 2.7]   0.05325728

(2.7, 155]   0.05179712
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What is the plot meant to look like? You have a single value for each range - it seems like that will produce a line rather than a rectangle?

Comment: Good point, I will assign an equal height of 0.1 to each value so they'll appear as rectangles. Purely aesthetic preference.

Comment: Exactly which commands have you tried?

Comment: `plot(rect(1, 0.05325728, 27, .06325728, densisty=NULL, angle=45, col = NA, border = NULL, lty = par("lty"), lwd = par("lwd")))`

Comment: You need to set up a `plot` region first, i.e. make a plot, to which the `rect`angle then can be added.

Answer (score 0):

Putting all your data into a `data.frame` might be helpful here:

```
dat <- data.frame(x1=c(1,27),x2=c(27,155),y=c(0.05325728,0.05179712))
#  x1  x2          y
#1  1  27 0.05325728
#2 27 155 0.05179712

# specify a height for the rectangles
hght <- 0.01

with(dat,plot(NA,xlim=c(min(x1),max(x2)),ylim=c(min(y),max(y)+hght),type="n"))
with(dat,rect(x1,y,x2,y+hght))
```

[image]

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to do either, although this is helpful for when I do.