# make barplot start from number other than 0 in base R graphics and plot values beneath this startpoint

Tags: r, graph

Is it possible to make a barplot start from a number other than 0 in base R graphics and to then plot values beneath this startpoint? For example, I would like to create a barplot where the origin on the y-axis is 1 and then to draw boxes that go up to 4 and down to -3.

For example, I would like to draw this barplot starting from 1, instead of drawing the bars from 0.

```
barplot(c(4,-3))
```

This question is distinct from: [Different Starting Point (not 0)  in barplot Y-Axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695502/different-starting-point-not-0-in-barplot-y-axis), which only plots values *above* a startpoint different from 0. I would like to plot them *below* the new startpoint.

Comment: This starts on 4: `barplot(table(mtcars$gear), ylim=c(4,14), xpd=F)`

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to draw values below 4 as well. I have updated the question to clarify this point.

Comment: @Devon - you might be better off just using `rect()` to draw rectangles on a plot - something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564100/plotting-values-as-rectangles-spanning-unequal-ranges-of-x/18564397#18564397

Comment: @thelatemail: Thanks! rect() is a good approach. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One hackish possibility -- tweak the values and adjust the axis accordingly:

```
barplot(c(4,-3)-1,axes=FALSE)
axis(side=2,at=(-3:4)-1,labels=(-3:4))
abline(h=0)
```